# Cross apply on columns on SQL server. Syntax error near )

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, unpivot, cross-apply

I am trying to unpivot several columns, but I can't find the way of solving the syntax error.

It says incorrect syntax near ')'.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT dates, times, locations, events
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES ('instance1', instance1),
            ('instance2', instance2),
            ('instance3', instance3),
            ('instance4', instance4)) as Items(locations, events)
```

Could it be because my SQL Server version does not support values properly and I need to store the values in a different table to refer them for cross apply?

[image]

Comment: what is instance1...4 column/variable from (the 2nd values object) [Demo](https://rextester.com/EVKB50243)  Expected results would help clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: The syntax looks correct.   Cross Apply goes back to 2005 and Values Constructor was introduced in 2008.    What version are you running.  Try select @@version

Comment: Without knowing your version it is hard to say if this is an issue with your version. What one are you running?

Comment: Running on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.7

Comment: The version of SSMS is irrelevant, it is the version of the instance you are connected to that matters. select @@VERSION

Comment: Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9999.0 Nov 15 2018 08:34:24 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Comment: According to the documentation on [table valued constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) they are not available in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since using [VALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) like that has issues in your Azure SQL Data Warehouse, switch to [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

```
SELECT dates, times, locations, events
FROM mytable t
UNPIVOT (events FOR [locations] IN ([instance1],[instance2],[instance3],[instance4])) AS unpvt;
```

Test [here](https://rextester.com/VGHB66192)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not keep the null values. Anyway to keep also the null values?

Comment: @zhivab Yes, I got a workaround for that, but it ain't pretty. Basically replace the table by a sub-query : `... FROM 
(select dates, times, isnull(instance1,'') as instance1, isnull(instance2,'') as instance2, isnull(instance3,'') as instance3, isnull(instance4,'') as instance4
from mytable) t ...`

Answer (score 2):

Pretty cool, I've never unpivoted that way. I always use the UNPIVOT command. But it does seem to work pretty well. Without knowing the structure of your mytable I don't know the problem, but I am guessing it doesn't have columns names instance1 through instance4?

Here's a self-contained working example:

```
select dates
      ,times
      ,locations
      ,events
from
(
    values
        ('20181225', 'noon', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
       ,('20181226', 'midnight', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
) mytable (dates, times, instance1, instance2, instance3, instance4)
cross apply
(
    values
        ('instance1', instance1)
       ,('instance2', instance2)
       ,('instance3', instance3)
       ,('instance4', instance4)
) as Items (locations, events);
```

Comment: Hi, I have added a picture at the top. I literally have copied your code and I find the same error

Comment: You were right. A SQL version problem. Works on Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8  Nov 2 2018.  But not SQL Data Warehouse.